# Failed to set user defined inspected property - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I received the following error when building my project:

```
Failed to set (layer.cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (NSLayoutConstraint): [<NSLayoutConstraint 0x7fbfd07c1210> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key layer.
```

I went through each of my constraints (in Interface Builder) one-by-one to see if I had accidentally defined any User Defined Runtime Attributes in the Identity Inspector, but don't believe I did.

Comment: Did you try searching for "layer.cornerRadius" in the Find navigator?

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I didn't realize it would be that simple.